# Online Accounts (Google)

Tags: settings, pantheon-mail

I receive an IMAP Authentication Failure when trying to log in to my Google Account through the 'Online Accounts' settings pane. I have read similar posts on this exchange but switching to 'Allow less secure apps' and '2FA' has not solved the problem. Can anyone shed any light? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I have solved my own issue. I set up an application password in my Google Account and this allowed 'Online Accounts' to sign in successfully.

Comment: I'm new and I've also had the same problem, I didn't understand how you solved it, could someone help me please... (Gmail)
Thanks.